# Magento 1.9.1 Most viewed products do not display any products after rearanging category from back end

Tags: magento-1.9

i have used below code to display most viewed products
Mostviewed.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: coopso-26-1
 * Date: 9/24/2015
 * Time: 10:54 AM
 */

class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Mostviewed extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
            ->addOrderedQty()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
            ->addViewsCount();
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

        $products->setPageSize(4)->setCurPage(1);
        $this->setProductCollection($products);
    }
}

and mostviewed.phtml

<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$this->setData('column_count',4);

$modules = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules')->children();
$modulesArray = (array)$modules;
if(isset($modulesArray['Tm_ProductListGallery'])) {
    $productgallerylist_helper = Mage::helper('productlistgallery');
    $productgallerylist_config = $productgallerylist_helper->getConfigData('home_grid');
}

?>
<?php
/*$products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
    ->setStoreId($storeId)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
    ->addViewsCount();
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_products);

*/?>
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
    <div class="widget widget-popular-products container">
        <div class="widget-title">
            <h2><?php echo $this->__('Most Popular Products') ?></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-products">
            <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
            <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
            <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>

                <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
                    <ul class="products-grid row">
                <?php endif ?>
                <li class="item <?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?> col-xs-12 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="wrapper-hover">

                        <div class="product-image-container">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image noSwipe">
                                <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($productgallerylist_config['image_width'], $productgallerylist_config['image_height']) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" /></a>
                            <?php
                            if ( !sizeof($_product->getData('list_swatch_attr_values')) ) :
                                if ($productgallerylist_config['active'] == '1'): ?>
                                    <ul class="product-thumbs">
                                        <?php
                                        $product_id = $_product->getId();
                                        $list_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
                                        $count_thumbs = 1;
                                        foreach ($list_product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                                            if($count_thumbs <= 3){?>
                                                <li class="product-thumb">
                                                    <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image', $image->getFile())->resize($productgallerylist_config['image_width']); ?>">
                                                        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $image->getFile())->resize($productgallerylist_config['image_width'], $productgallerylist_config['image_height']); ?>" alt="" width="<?php echo $productgallerylist_config['thumb_size_w']; ?>" height="<?php echo $productgallerylist_config['thumb_size_h']; ?>"/>
                                                    </a>
                                                </li>
                                            <?php }
                                            $count_thumbs++;
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </ul>
                                <?php endif;
                            endif; ?>
                            <div class="add-to-cart-grid">
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <?php

                                    if(in_array(121 , $_product->getCategoryIds())){?>

                                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Enquire Now') ?>" class="button btn-cart btn-enquire"onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() .'#enquiry-form'?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Enquire Now') ?></span></span></button>

                                    <?php  }else{?>

                                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                                    <?php }

                                    ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="product-info">
                            <h3 class="product-name">
                                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                                    <?php
                                    $small_name = strip_tags($_product->getName());
                                    if (strlen($small_name      ) < 28) echo($small_name);
                                    else { echo mb_substr($small_name, 0, 28,'UTF-8').'...';}
                                    ?>
                                </a>
                            </h3>
                            <?php
                            // Provides extra bloc->keepFrame(false)s on which to hang some features for products in the list
                            // Features providing UI elements targeting this block will display directly below the product name
                            if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                                $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                                foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                                    $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                                    $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);

                                    echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                                }
                            }
                            ?>

                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-widget-new-grid') ?>
                            <div class="add-to-cart-grid-2">
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <?php

                                    if(in_array(121 , $_product->getCategoryIds())){?>

                                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Enquire Now') ?>" class="button btn-cart btn-enquire"onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() .'#enquiry-form'?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Enquire Now') ?></span></span></button>

                                    <?php  }else{?>

                                        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                                    <?php }

                                    ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="actions">
                                <a class="more-info" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">More Info</a>
                                <ul class="add-to-links">
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                        <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                        <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>
                    <div class="label-product">
                        <?php if($_product->getData('new')){echo '<span class="new">'.$this->__('New').'</span>';  }?>
                        <?php if($_product->getData('sale')){echo '<span class="sale">'.$this->__('Sale').'</span>';  }?>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        jQuery('.btn-enquire').click(function(){

            setTimeout(function(){ jQuery('.enquiry-btn').trigger('click') }, 1000);

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

after rearranging categories from back end it displays blank

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but mine is in new_grid.phtml.

The solution I found is to reindex the data and clear the cache.